# Fastest way to Merge two arraylists

Tags: java, merge

I'm trying to merge two lists in sorted order, and I was wondering what the fastest way to merge them would be.
Currently, my algorithm is basically (ignoring syntax):

```
merge(a, b){
    newlist = new Arraylist()
    while(!a.isEmpty() && !b.isEmpty()){
        if(a.get(0) > b.get(0))
            newlist.add(a.remove(0))
        else 
            newlist.add(b.remove(0))
    }
    newlist.addAll(a)
    newlist.addAll(b)
    return newlist
}
```

Is there a faster way to do this kind of merge? I'm trying to reduce my runtime as much as possible as this function is called thousands of times with very large `ArrayList`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing from the front of an `ArrayList` has `O(N)` time complexity since all other elements need to be shifted. Instead, you could store the current index of the two `List`s and compare the elements at the the indexes each time to merge in `O(N)` time complexity overall (taking advantage of the fact that both `List`s are already sorted). Note that this is generally the method used in a merge sort. Also, it is better to pass the initial capacity to the `ArrayList` constructor if you know the size at the end.

```
public static List<Integer> merge(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b){
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(a.size() + b.size());
    int left = 0, right = 0;
    while(left < a.size() || right < b.size()){
        if(right == b.size() || left < a.size() && a.get(left) <= b.get(right)){
            result.add(a.get(left++));
        } else {
            result.add(b.get(right++));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*should using parallelism for the merging be similar fast?*

```
public static List<Integer> merge(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    return Stream.concat(a.parallelStream(), b.parallelStream())
        .sorted().collect(toList());
}
```

*(I really be interested in whether the speed advantage justifies the higher programming effort of the chosen solution.)*

Answer (score 1):

For any performance question: you'll have to measure with your own data.

In this case: initialize your Array List with the expected size, so that it doesn't need to be resized. But that is only a starting point